# Getting correct mouse position in a CSS scaled canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas, mootools, scale, mouse-position

I have been trying to take the logic of a couple simple MooTools operations and convert it to work with jQuery.

The logic I want is for this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rQkSF/) what it allows is to get accurate mouse position on a canvas element with css resizing.

I found the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152518/resizing-the-canvas-with-css-skews-up-mouse-action-help-me) on SO I have been working for a couple hours with no avail

I think I understand his logic but fitting for some reason I am not seeing results

Here is what I have done so far with arby's logic from his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152518/resizing-the-canvas-with-css-skews-up-mouse-action-help-me/4171800#4171800) commented out

```
// Get the change ratio for the new css set size
//var cssScale = [canvas.getSize().x / canvas.get('width'), canvas.getSize().y / canvas.get('height')];
var cssScale = [$('canvas').height() / $('canvas').attr('height'), $('canvas').width() / $('canvas').attr('$('canvas').height() / $('canvas').attr('height'),')]

//Create an object of the dimensions
// I think from my looking at the jsfiddle x&y is the position of the rect in his canvas
// and w&h are the height and width of that rect so it's not really necessary for my problem which
// is just getting mouse cords accuratly.
//this.setDims(x*cssScale[0], y*cssScale[1], w*cssScale[0], h*cssScale[1]);

// This is the offset of the clickable square in his code.
//this.offset = [x - this.dims[0], y - this.dims[1]];

// Now I do not know what this is
// If the offset is just for position in their code why is it used here
// How can you display just scaled mouse position
this.x = (x - this.offset[0]) / cssScale[0] + w * .5;
this.y = (y - this.offset[1]) / cssScale[1] + h * .5;
```

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do in the line where you set `cssScale`. You're dividing the width with the - height attribute divided by the height attribute - i.e. 1. Even then you have single quotes in a string delimited by single quotes. That should be giving you syntax errors.

I'm guessing you want something like `var cssScale = [$('canvas').width() / $('canvas').attr('width'), $('canvas').height() / $('canvas').attr('height')]`

Comment: I am not 100% sure either I am trying to convert the mootools logic to jquery, what I think is going on is you are getting the ratio of css growth/shrinkage with that line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've made a little [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ea4kc/) using plain javascript. I've got a [blog post](http://www.gkspk.com/view/programming/drag-n-drop-with-html-canvas/) explaning the process.

Take a look at the example with special note to where the variables `sx` and `sy` are being used. They're your scaling ratio. You'll basically need to apply this to any offsets within the canvas (i.e. *mouse position in the screen* minus the *canvas offset*).