# Canvas, how to take aspect ratio into account with mouse events?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, graphics

I have seen a few related posts on here but, from what I can understand, non that really fit my use case.

I have been reading [this post](http://www.sitepoint.com/modernize-your-html5-canvas-game/) on how to make a responsive canvas game and have followed the logic in step 1 and 2 and have positioned my canvas in the centre of the screen using the following:

```
<div id='game-screen'></div>

#game-screen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    translate: transform(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The div is what contains the canvas created in my Javascript.

I have my canvas width and height different to the "styled" width and height as per this tutorial. My canvas width and height is 1280 x 1024 pixels.

Now the problem I am having is that when binding my mouse move event to the canvas, the event.pageX and event.pageY variables are not proportionate to the scaled canvas. I have taken into consideration the offset left and top but I am unsure as to how I could "scale" the mouse x and y to relate to the canvas aspect ratio?

There seems to be around a 5-20px difference based on the stretched canvas size.

Thank you in advance, I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751458/getting-correct-mouse-position-in-a-css-scaled-canvas

Comment: My apologies, I did not find this in my search. This did the trick though so thank you very much =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the game screen position into the document. So with a substraction, you can get the relative mouse position.

```
var gameScreen = document.getElementById('game-screen');
gameScreen.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var gameScreenPosition = gameScreen.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = event.clientX - gameScreenPosition.left;
  var y = event.clientY - gameScreenPosition.top;
  alert(x + ' ' + y);
})
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/tzi/2cj8n8xt/

Comment: Hi, like I said i was taking into account the offsets but i appreciate the help.

Comment: Oups. I didn't understand, because in your CSS example your game board doesn't stretch

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. Sorry about that, thanks again for the advice though. Any help is appreciated!